# error Unrecognized command "build-android". Did you mean "run-android"?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

According to the official [React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.html#generating-the-release-aab),

I am trying to generate a `.aab` file for release. When I run the command

```
npx react-native build-android --mode=release
```

I get this error

> error Unrecognized command "build-android". Did you mean "run-android"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For react-native versions < 0.72. To generate .aab for release, you need to go to Android folder and run the following commands

```
.\gradlew clean
```

then

```
.\gradlew bundleRelease
```

According to this [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.71/signed-apk-android#generating-the-release-aab)